# Getting 304 status code on server console even after cache is deleted

Tags: reactjs, express, react-redux, request, http-status-code-304

I am working on MERN project, and I am using RTK Query to handle requests and caching. I keep getting 304 status code when I make a request from React, but 200 when it is through Postman. Furthermore, I tried to delete cache and local storage and cookies but nothing changes. The code is displayed on the server's console.

[image]

#### base/empty service (emptySlice.js)

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import { baseUrl } from "../utils/base_url";

export const emptySlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: `${baseUrl}/api/` }),
  tagTypes: ["Serviceman"],
  endpoints: (build) => ({}),
});
```

#### servicemenSlice.js

```
import { emptySlice } from "./emptySlice";

export const serviceMenSlice = emptySlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getServiceMen: build.query({
      query: () => "serviceman",
      providesTags: ["Serviceman"],
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetServiceMenQuery } = serviceMenSlice;
```

#### index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { ApiProvider } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/react";
import { emptySlice } from "./services/emptySlice";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <ApiProvider api={emptySlice}>
      <App />
    </ApiProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
reportWebVitals();
```

#### store.js

I am not using the store since ApiProvider in the index.js. I actually tried using the store with the required middleware, but the result is the same.

#### Landing.jsx

Here is where the error occurs when serviceMen is fetched.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Header from "../../components/Header/Header";
import ServiceSearchBar from "../../components/ServiceSearchBar/ServiceSearchBar";
import ServiceCategoryList from "../../components/ServiceCategoryList/ServiceCategoryList";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getServices } from "../../features/service/serviceSlice";
import MainContentWrapper from "../../components/MainContentWrapper/MainContentWrapper";
import { getAllServiceMen } from "../../features/serviceMan/serviceManSlice";
import ServiceMan from "../../components/ServiceMan/ServiceMan";
import Footer from "../../components/Footer/Footer";
import PageWrapper from "../../components/PageWrapper/PageWrapper";
import Loading from "../../components/Loading/Loading";
import Badge from "../../components/Badge/Badge";
import { useGetServiceMenQuery } from "../../services/servicemenSlice";
import { useGetServicesQuery } from "../../services/serviceSlice";

const Landing = () => {
  const {
    data: serviceMen,
    isLoading,
    isFetching,
    isError,
    error,
  } = useGetServiceMenQuery();

  const {
    data: services,
    isLoading: isLoadingServices,
    isFetching: isFetchingServices,
    isError: isErrorServices,
  } = useGetServicesQuery();

  const [activeServiceMen, setActiveServiceMen] = useState([]);

  if (isLoading || isFetching) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  if (isError) {
    return <h1>{error}</h1>;
  }

  const serviceMenList = serviceMen.map((serviceMan) => (
    <ServiceMan key={serviceMan._id} serviceMan={serviceMan} />
  ));

  const activeServices = services.filter((service) => service.active);

  return (
    <PageWrapper>
      <Header />
      <MainContentWrapper>
        <ServiceSearchBar />
        <section className="grid grid-col lg:grid-cols-4 w-full gap-5 items-start mb-10">
          <div className="flex col-span-full lg:col-span-1 flex-col gap-2">
            <Badge text="Services" number={activeServices.length} />
            <ServiceCategoryList services={activeServices} />
          </div>

          <div className="col-span-full lg:col-span-3 w-full justify-center">
            <Badge text="Service Men" number={activeServiceMen.length} />
            <div className="flex flex-col gap-4 mt-5 pr-6">
              {activeServiceMen.length > 0 ? (
                { serviceMenList }
              ) : (
                <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
                  <p className="text-black">No service man yet</p>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </MainContentWrapper>
      <Footer />
    </PageWrapper>
  );
};

Landing.propTypes = {};

export default Landing;
```

Comment: There is a `401` error code, not `304`. Also, looks like `serviceMen` is not an array (or whatever type with a `map` method)

Comment: The 304 status code is displayed on the server console. Also, the serviceMen is supposed to be an array of objects from the server, but since nothing is returned from the server due to 304, it is null.

Comment: You haven't provided any code so how could anything be fixed? If `serviceMen` is `null` like you said, then put `if (serviceMen !== null)` guards before calling `.map`.

Comment: I have edited the question by adding code. Providing the guard will help to avoid the error. However, my problem is the fact that the server does not send the data even though the cache is deleted.

Comment: Hm, not quite sure but what happens if you put `'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'` on the request?